# Is in this case distance same as displacement?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, distance, displacement

I have this graph, and I need to know the ***displacement*** in the interval **from 0 to 5 seconds**, so I found the area of the rectangle that you can see there. A = w*h, which means X = (5 seconds)*(20 m/s), then **displacement = 100 meters**.[image]

But now I have this other problem, in the following graph I need to found the distance in the interval of **0 to 5 seconds**, in the previous graph I had to found the **displacement**, but now I need the ***distance***, but should it be the same? because actually it is just a magnitude, so maybe I need to found the area again, or should I use pythagoras?, I hope you can answer this easy question, I would appreciate if you explain why, thank you all.[image]

Comment: Distance traveled is the integral of the absolute value of the velocity; displacement is just the integral of the velocity. Both of which with respect to time, of course.

Comment: In this case, the distance travelled between zero and five seconds is simply the area underneath which is $50 \, m$. For this example, we would have that the distance is the same as the displacement, but it is not always the case.

Comment: This is a site that is *not* meant as a platform to get your work done for you. As it stands right now, your question seems to simply ask for a solution, rather than showing an interest in understanding the underlying physics. As such, it is a "homework"-type question which does not show sufficient effort, rendering it *off-topic* on this site.

Please review our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) to see what kind of homework questions are allowed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case *distance* and *displacement* mean the same thing. Just calculate the area under the second graph as you did for the first one.

The difference between *distance* and *displacement* arises when the direction you're moving in changes. For example suppose I travel one mile north then one mile south - obviously this brings me back to where I started. The *distance* I have travelled is two miles, but the *displacement* measures how far from my start point I ended up. So in this case the *displacement* would be zero.

In your exercises you're moving in a straight line (or at least I assume so) so the distance from your starting point is the same as the total distance you've travelled.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a little bit hard to see, the second graph axes are time (tiempo) on X, and velocity (Velocidad) on Y.

You should be able to compute the position of the object after 5 seconds (it's not clear whether the velocity is supposed to be $0$ at $t=0$, or $5 m/s$ - the axis is not labeled at that point - but I expect that you have been taught how to compute position from velocity.

And when you know the position, you can compute the displacement, distance, …

Now if you have not been taught about integrating velocity, you might be able to estimate the average velocity instead. And if you can do that, you can state that (for the purpose of this question) the distance is given by the average velocity multiplied by the time.

Think you can take it from here?